# Flask SQLAlchemy query SAP HANA on VIEW

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, hana

I'm trying to develop a microservice with flask and SQLAlchemy to execute a query on a View from SAP HANA. Obviously the View does not have a primary key so how I can do this and fix this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper[Dom("TABLE_NAME")] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'TABLE_NAME'

My code:

```
base = declarative_base()
class Dom(base):
    __tablename__ = "TABLE_NAME"
    OBJECT_DOMAIN = Column(Integer)
    VALUE= Column(String)
    DESCRIPTION= Column(String)

factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = factory()
for instance in session.query(Dom).all():
    print(instance)
```

Comment: `Obviously the View does not have a primary key ` obviously you are wrong. HANA has many view types and some of them def have primary key https://visualbi.com/blogs/sap/sap-bw-hana/sap-hana/cds-views-key-column/ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Defining-a-primary-key-in-an-Attribute-view-in-SAP-HANA